How to split OBX segments of variable length separated by "`" and map to individual JSON fields using Javascript
I am mapping HL7 messages into JSON and came a across a scenario that I am unsure of.
I need to convert OBX segments, like the below:
OBX|1|CE|2643^MED LIST&PRESCRIBED MEDICATIONS^||VYVANSE`RITALIN`CONCERTA`VIVITROL`BRIXADI`SUBLOCADE

And the individual entries in the OBX.5.1 need to be mapped to ['order']['drugs']['drugName'] like below:
"drugs" : [
    {
      "drugName" : "VYVANSE"
    },
    {
      "drugName" : "RITALIN"
    },
    {
      "drugName" : "CONCERTA"
    },        
    {
      "drugName" : "VIVITROL"
    },
    {
      "drugName" : "BRIXADI"
    },
    {
      "drugName" : "SUBLOCADE"
    },
],

I usually use the below, but it only maps the whole segment and not the individual back ticked entries in the segment.
var drg = -1;
for each (seg in msg..OBX)
    {
        var obx2_1 = seg['OBX.2']['OBX.2.1'].toString();
    if ( obx2_1.match(/CE/) )
        {
            if(seg['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'].toString() != "NONE")
                {
                    drg++;
                    tmp['order']['drugs'][drg] = {};
                    var drug = tmp['order']['drugs'][drg];
                    drug['drugName'] = seg['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'].toString();
                }
        };
        if(obx2_1.toString()=="SpecInstruc"){
            tmp['order']['comments'] = seg['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'].toString();
        }
        
    };

The number of drugs in the OBX.5.1 may be variable as well as the total OBXs themselves, like so:
OBX|1|CE|2643^MED LIST&PRESCRIBED MEDICATIONS^||VYVANSE`RITALIN`CONCERTA`VIVITROL`BRIXADI`SUBLOCADE
OBX|1|CE|2641^MED LIST&PRESCRIBED MEDICATIONS^||AMBIEN`XANAX

How can I achieve this?

The ^~\&| are standard delimiters. The back tick is not. It is up to you how to parse it.

That the back tick is not a standard delimiter doesn't make this opinion-based. It's still an objectively answerable "how to" question.

You could test if the string in OBX.5.1 contains a back tick using the indexOf() string method. If so, split the string into an array using the split() array methed, and then iterate over the array using a for...of statement to set the properties you want.
